# Spring: - How can we get Bean if context are loaded from web.xml?

Tags: java, spring

I am learning `spring` which is being used in my project.I found the `contextConfigLocation` entry in my web.xml

```
 /WEB-INF/context/*-context.xml
 classpath:/context/database-context.xml
 classpath:/context/database-service-context.xml
 classpath:/context/business-process-management-service-context.xml
```

and listener

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

In a core project which I read like below

```
 Resource r=new ClassPathResource("applicationContext.xml");  
 BeanFactory factory=new XmlBeanFactory(r);  
 Employee s=(Employee)factory.getBean("e");
```

But could not figure out how things are working and where `getBean()` function is called ?

Comment: You don't get beans, you get them injected. Spring is bootstrapping your application, for the rest use dependency injection.

Comment: shall I use this dependency injection in core project

Comment: could you please provide some demo ....

Answer (score -1):

You can retrieve the WebContext with this method:

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/support/WebApplicationContextUtils.html#getWebApplicationContext%28javax.servlet.ServletContext%29

Comment: thanks for answer but I am just reading the code to get the work flow. not for make any changes